# Javascript - Checkbox checked condition

Tags: javascript

I have a input checkbox, i want to run different block of code, when checkbox is ticked & vice versa.

```
function checkboxEvent(){
    if checked{ ....Run this block  }
    else { ....Run this block  }
}
```

How to identify in function whether checkbox is checked or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
if(document.getElementById('id of the check box here').checked){
    // it is checked. Do something
}
else{
    // it isn't checked. Do something else
}
```

`.checked` property returns a `boolean` indicating whether the element is checked or not.

Answer (score 2):

you can check check box value as follows

```
document.getElementById("myCheck").checked
```

So your function would be something like ..

```
function checkboxEvent(){
    if (document.getElementById("myCheck").checked){ ....Run this block  }
    else { ....Run this block  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

its very easy to find checked property, just use below code

```
if(  $('input[name="transport"]').is(':checked') ) {
            alert('checked');
alert($(this).attr('id'));//To get ID of checkBox
        }
```

Comment: Checkout the javascript tag information: Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the checked property when the check box is clicked, do:

```
// onchange event listens when the checkbox's state is changed
document.getElementById('box').onchange = function(){
    if(this.checked) alert("y");
    else alert("no");
};
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FsfL8/)**

`.checked` is a boolean indicating state of checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

< input type="checkbox id="remember" >

```
<script>

var remember = document.getElementById('remember');
    if (remember != null && remember.checked){
        alert("checked") ;
    }else{
        alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.")
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function checkboxEvent() {

    var boxes = document.getElementsByName("chkbox");

    for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if (boxes[i].checked) {


        console.log(" Checked!");

    } else {
        console.log("not checked");

    }

}

}
```

The `for` loop will look up through all of your checkboxes and see if they are checked.

Alternatively, you can use `.hasAtrribute` .You can find more info about `.hasAttribute` **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_hasattribute.asp)**